# Redirect email for redirected domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I have two domain names with a registrar, one points to a server running plesk with a subscription setup to host the website. The second domain name simply redirects to the first using the registrars forwarding.

My client needs to have an email address on the second domain name, that in turn redirects any emails to an altogether separate email address.

Would I somehow be able to do this using DNS records, or would I need to setup the second domain on the Plesk hosting, just to be able to forward emails?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, the normal domain is `example.com` and `example.net` is the alias which should redirect.

In DNS you have to specify the responsible mail server using the `MX` record, the MX for `example.net` would be `mail.example.com` are whatever the MX record for `example.com` is. Then all mails for `example.net` get delivered to the same mailserver as for `example.com`. The mailserver `mail.example.com` has also to be configured to accept mails for `example.net` otherwise it rejects all mails with that domain.

There is no mechanism for DNS which redirects mails, i.e. changes the domain of the recipient address (!), so the mail server has to act as destination for both domains.

On the domain server itself, the mails can be handled in whatever way you want, you can replace the domain of the original recipient and deal with it like it has the other (but I don't recommend that). Or - the simplest and recommended - just deliver independent of the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So would I still need an entry in Plesk (a subscription) for example.net to capture the email, or if I add a new address for example.net in the subscription for example.com - would that work? I just don't want to use up one of my licences just for email forwarding on that example.net domain.

Comment: I don't know Plesk and can't say what you need to configure there at minimum. Questions about Plesk and other management software is also [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here. If this answer was helpful, consider upvoting and accepting it.